# Python concurrent.futures run threads in pool until a result is found

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I want to run threads in a ThreadPoolExecutor until one of them give me a specific result. For now my code looks like this:

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)
futures = [pool.submit(g,i) for i in range (4)]
j = 4
for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    if f.result():
        break # OK the result is found
    else:
        j += 1
        futures.append(pool.submit(g,j))
```

but the `append` in last line seems to have no effect on the `as_completed` generator. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I also recently found this out.  I didn't look at the source but it appears that `concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)` gets evaluated - it must use a copy of the sequence initially provided because it doesn't recognize updates/additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep checking each future in the sequence till you find one that is done.

```
from collections import deque
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)

futures = deque(pool.submit(g,i) for i in range (4))
j = 4
result = False
while not result:
    while not futures[0].done():
        futures.rotate()
    future = futures.popleft()
    result = future.result()
    if not result:
        j += 1
        futures.append(pool.submit(g,j))
```

---

Here is a similar solution using `concurrent.futures.wait`.
First a callable for testing purposes:

```
import random
class F:
    def __init__(self, threshold=.03):
        self._bool = random.random() < threshold
    def __call__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        time.sleep(random.random())
        return self
    def __bool__(self):
        return self._bool
    def __str__(self):
        return f'I am number {self.n}'
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'I am number {self.n}'
```

Solution

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4)
j = 4
futures = [pool.submit(F(),i) for i in range(j)]
result = False
while not result:
    #print(f'there are {len(futures)} futures')
    maybe_futures = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')
    futures = maybe_futures.not_done
    # more than one may have completed(?)
    for future in maybe_futures.done:
        temp = future.result()
        if not temp:
            j += 1
            futures.add(pool.submit(F(),j))
        else:
            result = temp
            break
```

---

Another solution using a callback (uses the callable *above*): not sure what happens if a future completes before the callback gets added.

```
completed_futures = collections.deque()
result = False
def callback(future, completed=completed_futures):
    completed.append(future)

j = 4

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 4) as pool:
    #initial tasks
    for i in range(j):
        future = pool.submit(F(),i)
        future.add_done_callback(callback)
    while not result:    # is this the same as - while True: ?
        while not completed_futures:
            pass
        while completed_futures:
            future = completed_futures.popleft()
            result = future.result()
            if result:
                break
            j += 1
            future = pool.submit(F(),j)
            future.add_done_callback(callback)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am just guessing that this version is more cpu intensive than with `as_completed` due to the busy waiting line 7 (but I don't know how as_completed is implemented)

Comment: Maybe, Except as you found out, it doesn't work the way you want it to.  The source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L196) - it makes a set of the `fs` argument so you cannot add to it after it is evaluated.

Comment: The solution with `wait` is exactly what I was looking for! But there is a problem in the `for` loop line 9: `futures` is initialized with `list(maybe_futures.not_done)` at each iteration, so the elements appended are lost.

Comment: Moved that statement, thnx.